# Python function that calculates lower and upper bound using quantiles

Tags: python, function, quantile

I have a dataset name data. I would like to calculate the Lower and Upper value for multiple numeric variables: Loan, Amount, Value, LTV, UR. Instead of computing them one by one, how can I automate the following python code?

```
#Loan
Q1= data['LOAN'].quantile(q=0.25)
Q3= data['LOAN'].quantile(q=0.75)  
IQR= Q3 - Q1   
Lower = (Q1 - 1.5*IQR) 
Upper = (Q3 + 1.5*IQR) 
print('Loan')
print(Lower)
print(Upper)
```

Comment: why can't you use a for loop? `for col in ('loan', 'amount', 'value', luv', 'ur'): ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd define an array with the colum names, then i'll cycle all the columns calling a function that calculates the values:

```
names =['LOAN', 'AMOUNT','VALUE','LUV','UR']
for column in data[names]:        
    x,y=calculateLowerUpper(column)
    print (column)
    print(x)
    print(y)

def calculateLowerUpper(column):
    q1= data['LOAN'].quantile(q=0.25)
    q3= data['LOAN'].quantile(q=0.75)  
    iqr= q3 - q1   
    lower = (q1 - 1.5*iqr) 
    upper = (q3 + 1.5*iqr) 
    return lower,upper
```